Multiple rate-determining steps and rate expression
I am trying to understand the concept of the rate laws governing hydrogen evolution of platinum. More specifically, I am trying to understand the multiple occurrence of a rds to the overall rate law of a reaction.
In the lecture, we talked about how there are three possible steps; the Volmer-step, the Heyrovsky step and the Tafel step:

For simplicity, lets talk about the Volmer-Tafel mechanism. We suppose the Volmer step to be very slow and rate-determining, and the Tafel step to be really fast; therefore, the Volmer reaction has to happen twice in order for the Tafel step to take place.
My professor derived the following rate expression:

This rate expression seems to agree with literature. However, I am not able to understand how neither the reaction order in protons nor the "Tafel slope" (exponential term, similar to Arrhenius) is not affected by the fact that the rate-determining step has to happen twice. I guess this is also a question in more general terms.
Why would multiple occurrence of an RDS not alter the rate expression?

In case I you only consider the electrochemical hydrogen reduction and its inverse reaction
$$ \ce{H^+ + M + e <=>[k_1][k_{-1}] MH} \hspace{3ex}[1] $$
The rate of reaction [1] is given by
$$ \ce{ v_1 = k_1 c_{H^+} (1 -\theta_H)} $$
where $\ce{c_{H^+}}$ is the surface concentration of hydrogen, and $\theta_H$ is the surface coverage of adsorbed hydrogen.
Since reaction [1] is an electron tranfer reaction on an electrode surface, it rate depends on the electrode potential (E) - or overpotential ($\ce{\eta\,=\,E -E_0}$). If the oxidation step at the applied potential, $\ce{k_1(\eta)}$ is given by
$$ \rm{k_1 = k^0 e^{-\alpha f \eta} }$$
where $\rm{\alpha}$ is the symmetry factor and $\rm{f = RT/F}$. It is natural that this expression reminds you of the Arrhenius equation. Actually, you can interpret as describing the effect of the electrode potential of the height of the reaction barrier.
Thus,
$$ \ce{ v_1 = k^0 e^{-\alpha f \eta} c_{H^+} (1 -\theta_H)} $$
For low coverage this expression simplifies to
$$ \ce{ v_1 \approx k^0 e^{-\alpha f \eta} c_{H^+} } $$
Since reaction [1] is the RDS, the overall rate depends on the rate of this step, and
$$ \ce{ v_{HER} = \frac{v_1}{\color{red}{2}} = \frac{k^0}{2} e^{-\alpha f \eta} c_{H^+}} $$
Guess the 2 factor is subsumed into the experimental $\ce{k^0_{exp}}$. Maybe I am missing something.

I see your derivation makes sense... leaves me wondering if the factor of 1/2 is consumed in k_0. But one thing: Lets assume we have a similar problem and it is not an electrochemical one, but the reaction still has to go through the rate-determining step twice. Then we also have to add a factor of 1/2?

I would think so. The 2 factor comes from the definition of reaction rate. In the case of the Tafel reaction, if you consider the formation of  $\ce{H2}$, you would have  $$-\frac{\ce{d|MH|}}{\ce{dt}} = \frac{1}{\nu_{\ce{H2}}} \ce{k_2 |MH|} $$ where the $\nu_{\ce{H2}}$ represent the stoichometric coefficient of MH in the reaction.

On the other hand, I think it is not an uncommon practice to subsume this factor into the rate coefficient (or rate constant) since you can not distinguish it experimentally .

MH is adsorbed hydrogen on metal surface, yes?

That's right. In my first comment $\ce{\nu_{H2}}$ should read $\ce{\nu_{MH}}$.

Thanks a lot for the explanation
